# how do I hot swap my code in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to Edit and Continue in Visual Studio 2010 without pausing execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581969/is-it-possible-to-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2010-without-pausing-execut)

How can I edit my c# code while debugging and replace the running code ?
* I am use to other IDE's where you just compile and it automatically hot swap

Comment: What language are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Edit & Continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x17d7wxw.aspx).