# Better Edit and Continue workflow in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, edit-and-continue

I use Edit and Continue all the time in Visual Studio, but the whole process is kind of a hassle. This is my current workflow while I'm running something in debug mode:

```
1) Press the "pause" button (or hotkey: ctrl+alt+pause).

If a new file opened:
    2) Close its tab.
Else (it scrolled to a new place in a file I already have open):
    2) Try to remember where in the file I used to be, and scroll back there.

3) Make code changes.

4) Find the nearest semicolon, delete it, then re-type it.

5) Press the "play" button (or hotkey: F5).

6) Watch the Output window to make sure it noticed my changes and recompiled.

7) Start over from step 1 if it didn't notice my changes.
```

But it would be nice if it worked like this instead:

```
1) Make code changes.

2) Hit some button (F5?) to apply.
```

So the three main problems I have are:

1. The weird semicolon thing: Sometimes Visual Studio doesn't notice that I changed the file and resumes execution without my changes, but I found that removing then adding a semicolon almost always gets it to notice.
2. Pausing execution jumps to the current line being executed.
3. I have to pause/resume execution manually.

Is there any way to streamline the process by fixing those things? (Even fixing just one would be nice.) I'm using Visual Studio 2005, but I'm guessing newer versions have at least some of these problems too.

I found a similar question, but it didn't quite help me: [Is it possible to Edit and Continue in Visual Studio 2010 without pausing execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581969/is-it-possible-to-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2010-without-pausing-execut/)

Comment: I would hit pause, then select 'Apply code changes' from the debug menu. They you don't have to hope that Visual Studio notices your changes. Then hit F5 to continue.

Comment: @Baldrick
I gave that a try, but had the same problem. "Apply code changes" was sometimes not available.